# I don't see app/code folder even after creating my custom theme. Should I need to create it manually?

Tags: magento2

I have downloaded Magento 2 community edition from Magento site. I wanted to add a free Magento banner slide extension from https://github.com/Magestore/Bannerslider-Magento2

In the description given in this link, I need to add the folder to **app/code** folder. What should I do otherwise..?? In many other tutorials, I find asking me to add files or modify the contents of app/code. Please give me a suggestion I am very new to Magento 2
[image]

Comment: Need to create `app/code` folder.

Comment: You have to create manually CODE under APP

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh  thank you so much it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Fresh magento installation with

```
app/code
```

folder doesn't exist. 
so You have to manually create your code folder inside app folder.

**When you want to add new extension in Magento 2 you have to first time create code folder and inside code folder you can place your new extension.**

Answer (score 1):

Magento provides many methods to install it, i.e. using **composer**, by **direct download from Magento's website** and by **GIT checkout**.

If you install Magento using **GIT repository checkout**, then the installation folder contains **`app/code`** folder by default. Otherwise, Magento's core code exists under **`vendor`** folder. Every time you need to add new/enhance existing functionality in Magento, you need to add your code into **`app/code`** folder.

If **`app/code`** folder does not exist, you can create it manually.

I hope I was clear enough to rectify your doubt.

Please let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: thank you for a brief explanation..!! Can you tell me how to install magento 2 from git repository..!! can you explain the steps ..I would like to give it a try..!!  @Mohit Kumr Arora

Comment: There are some restrictions in GIT method. For example installations via GIT checkout can not be updated via admin panel. If you want to contribute to Magento's features enhancements, then GIT method is useful for you.

Comment: All three methods are given in detail at this link: http://inchoo.net/magento-2/how-to-install-magento-2/

Please let me know if it helped.